# Web scraping with R error

Tags: r, web-scraping, xmlroot

I trying to scrape sainsburys.co.uk, I'm running the next code in R

```
doc <- htmlTreeParse('http://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/fruit-veg/all-fruit#langId=44&storeId=10151&catalogId=10122&categoryId=12545&parent_category_rn=12518&top_category=12518&pageSize=30&orderBy=FAVOURITES_FIRST&searchTerm')

rootNode <- xmlRoot(doc)
```

but I have this error:

```
Error in x$children[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the `httr` library:

```
library(XML)
library(httr)
url <- 'http://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/fruit-veg/all-fruit#langId=44&storeId=10151&catalogId=10122&categoryId=12545&parent_category_rn=12518&top_category=12518&pageSize=30&orderBy=FAVOURITES_FIRST&searchTerm'
doc <- content(GET(url),type="text/html")
xmlValue(doc["//title"][[1]])
# [1] "All fruit | Sainsbury's"
```